# How does premultiplied alpha pixels work with RGB values higher than alpha

Tags: graphics, core-graphics

I am working on an app and on Android I was able to use regular RGBA, but on iOS they only support premultiplied RGBA.
My understanding is you just multiply the RGB values by the alpha, so something like 0xff000070 (regular) would translate to to 0x70000070 (premultiplied) and that would represent a value of 100% red intensity with 43% occlusion.

So what happens in the case of 0xff000070 (premultiplied) would that mean 227% red intensity or how does that work?

In the image below this shows the top being 0x00700070 and the bottom being 0x00ff0070 both premultiplied.

[image: Test Case]

Answer (score 0):

Given *source* (foreground), *destination* (background), and *result* (final framebuffer value):

For premultiplied alpha:

```
green_result = green_destination * (255 - alpha_source) + green_source
```

For non-premultiplied alpha:

```
green_result = green_destination * (255 - alpha_source) + green_source * alpha_source
```

It's apparent, as you have noticed, that it's possible, with premultiplied alpha, to perform a blending operation that produces a `green_result` value that exceeds 255 (the maximum value that can be represented by an 8 bit integer).

In general, the behaviour of having a `green_source` component that exceeds `alpha_source` is undefined.   And it may result in an arithmetic overflow.

Depending on the implementation being used, you may find that the `green_result` value may be *clamped* to a 0-255 range, or you may find that it just takes the lower 8 bits of the sum.  It depends on the implementation.  But most implementations will just add in the `green_source` value, as described by the formula I wrote above, even when an overflow does not occur.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what you're saying is its undefined.

Another question is wouldn't this lose granularity or does it not matter when actually being drawn?

for example depending on how rounding is handled lets say the alpha is 0x10 and red is 0x70 and blue is 0x7f, when multiplied with remainder thrown out they both are 0x7 and would look the same(intensity) on the result. Would this have been the case if it were not premultiplied?